# SQL query with JOIN many-to-many table

Tags: sql

I have three tables (simplified):

Item  (Id, ItemName)

```
1 Item1
2 Item2
3 Item3
```

Supplier (Id, SupplierName)

```
1 Suppler1
2 Suppler2
```

SupplierM2MItem (ItemId, SupplierId) – foreign keys

```
1 1
1 2
2 1
```

I need to get all suppliers for all items like this:

```
Item1 Supplier1
Item1 Supplier2
Item2 Supplier1
Item3
```

I believe it's not hard to achieve this but I can't. Can you please help

Comment: Have you tried anything?  An `inner join` does most of what you want, although you need an outer join for the fourth row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The right solution uses outer joins:

```
SELECT I.Item, S.Supplier
FROM Item I LEFT JOIN
     SupplierM2MItem S2I 
     ON I.Id = S2I.ItemID LEFT JOIN
     Supplier S
     ON S2I.SupplierID = S.ID;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it's an inner join plus an outer join. Try this:

```
SELECT I.Item, S.Supplier
FROM Supplier S
LEFT OUTER JOIN
SupplierM2MItem S2I 
ON S2I.SupplierID = S.ID
INNER JOIN
Item I
ON I.Id = S2I.ItemID
```